# Window Not Scrolling When Content Fills It Up So New Content Not Visible Without Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, autoscroll

I am currently constructing a roulette system programme ( this is more to keep me from betting than to bet! ) and am just doing the basic framework but already hit a problem with the main window '#results' not scrolling when it is filled with the results. The scroll needs to follow the latest line of content so the latest returned from the input in the modal box is always showing at the bottom. I have spent hours on lots of possible solutions to no avail.

Here is the code: ( i apologise for the length of the full script )

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
   
    <div id="results">
        </div>

  
  
    <div id="modal">
    <div id="modal-content">
      <p>Select a number between 0 and 36:</p>
      <div id="numberButtons"></div>
      <button id="close-button" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <style>
  
  
    /* The modal background */
    #modal {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    /* The modal content */
    #modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fefefe;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 18%;
    border: 3px solid black;
  
    }




    /* The close button */
    #close-button {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #numberButtons button {
      color: white;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size:30px;
    font-weight:600;
    }
    
    #modal.inactive{
    opacity: 0.2;
    }

    </style>
    <script>
  
    var bankRoll = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter your starting bankroll:"));
    if(isNaN(bankRoll)){
    bankRoll = parseFloat(prompt("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number for your starting bankroll:"));
    }
  

    bankRoll = bankRoll.toFixed(2);
  
    var spinNumber=0;
    
    
    
    var backline="";
    
    
    var isDragging = false;
    var currentX;
    var currentY;
    var initialX;
    var initialY;
    var xOffset = 0;
    var yOffset = 0;

    const modalContent = document.querySelector("#modal-content");

    modalContent.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
    modalContent.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd);
    modalContent.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);

    function dragStart(e) {
      initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
      initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;

      if (e.target === modalContent) {
        isDragging = true;
      }
    }

    let inactivityTimeout;

    function dragEnd(e) {
    initialX = currentX;
    initialY = currentY;

    isDragging = false;
    clearTimeout(inactivityTimeout);
    inactivityTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    modal.classList.add("inactive")
    }, 15000)
    }


    function drag(e) {
    if (e.buttons === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
    currentY = e.clientY - initialY;

    xOffset = currentX;
    yOffset = currentY;

    setTranslate(currentX, currentY, modalContent);
    clearTimeout(inactivityTimeout);
    modal.classList.remove("inactive")
    }
    }



    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

    function getNumberType(number) {
    
      if (number === 0) {
        return "green";
      } else if (number % 2 === 0) {
        return "even";
      } else {
        return "odd";
      }
    }

    function roulette(number) {
      // Determine the color of the number
      var color;
      if (number === 0) {
        color = "Green";
      } else if (number === 1 || number === 3 || number === 5 || number === 7 || number === 9 || number ===        12 || number === 14 || number === 16 || number === 18 || number === 19 || number === 21 || number === 23 || number === 25 || number === 27 || number === 30 || number === 32 || number === 34 || number === 36) {
        color = "Red";
      } else {
        color = "Black";
      }

      // Map the color names to CSS color values
      if (color === "Green") {
        return "rgb(0, 128, 0)";
      } else if (color === "Red") {
        return "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
      } else {
        return "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      }
    }


    function backgroundline() {
       if (spinNumber % 2 === 0) {
        backline="#D3D3D3"
      } else {
       backline="#E5E4E2";
      }
    }
    

    

    function spin(number) {
    // Determine the color of the number
    var color = roulette(number);
    spinNumber= spinNumber+1;
 
    bankRoll=bankRoll-10;
    backgroundline();
    // Display the result
    var resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
    var resultHTML = `${number}`;
  
    resultHTML = `<div style="padding:10px 0; background: ${backline};vertical-align:middle;margin-bottom:-      20px;">
  
    <div style="padding:5px; display: inline-block; background: yellow; color:black;vertical-align:middle;   width:30px; text-align:right;">${spinNumber}</div>
  
    <div style="margin: 0 10px; display:inline-block; width: 70px; text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">£ ${bankRoll}</div>
  
   <div style="color: white; padding: 5px; display: inline-block; width:30px; padding-top:15px;vertical-align:middle; font-size: 25px; font-weight:600; height:30px; text-align:center; background-color: ${color}; ">${resultHTML}</div>
  
   </div>
  
   <br style="height:0px;"/>`;
 
   resultsDiv.innerHTML += resultHTML;
    
   }
   // Set up the buttons
   for (let i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
   let button = document.createElement("button");
   button.innerHTML = i;
   button.style.backgroundColor = roulette(i);
   button.addEventListener("click", function() {
     spin(i);
   });
   document.getElementById("numberButtons").appendChild(button);
   }

   function closeModal() {
   // Get the modal element
   var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

   // Remove the modal element from the DOM
   modal.remove();
   }
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I have tried lots of solutions on Stack Overflow and across the Internet further field that I thought might work but it just doesn't seem to want to do it.

Comment: window should scroll down when items are more than viewport? is that you means

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, the window needs to scroll down so the latest line is shown automatically, at the moment it stays showing the early content.

Comment: please try the code i have attached below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding element in Results div you have to call this function.

add this function
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
after this line
resultsDiv.innerHTML += resultHTML;

Comment: Absolutely brilliant Ahmed, thanks so much, works a treat!

Comment: Sorry Ahmed, it is working fine on the full page but when I change the size of #results div it isn't working.

Comment: How do you change size?

Comment: I sorted it with a little bit ofhelp from Open AI! ( I hope this is not a bad name on here! )! The line had to be changed to

document.getElementById('results').scrollTop = document.getElementById('results').scrollHeight;

Thanks again for your help, Ahmed.

Comment: Have just added feedback, but I’m new here and says I need at least 15 feedbacks before they register, will work on this Ahmed.